# HAVING clause in one query with subquery

Tags: php, mysql, sql, having

Is it possible to have multiple HAVING in one query?

Here is my sample query:

```
SELECT household_tbl.household_connector_id AS h_id
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(household_connector_id)
        FROM household_tbl
        WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
            AND hh_phic_status = 1
            AND age >= 21
            AND age_category = "Year"
        ) + (
        SELECT COUNT(hh_members_connector_id)
        FROM tbl_household_members
        WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
            AND hh_phic_status = 1
            AND hh_age >= 21
            AND hh_age_category = "Year"
        ) AS total_phic
    , (
        SELECT COUNT(household_connector_id)
        FROM household_tbl
        WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
            AND hh_phic_status = 1
            AND age >= 21
            AND age_category = "Year"
            AND (
                hh_phic_membership_category = "ng sponsored"
                OR hh_phic_membership_category = "Sponsored-NG(DOH)"
                )
        ) + (
        SELECT COUNT(hh_members_connector_id)
        FROM tbl_household_members
        WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
            AND hh_phic_status = 1
            AND hh_age >= 21
            AND hh_age_category = "Year"
            AND (
                hh_phic_membership_category = "ng sponsored"
                OR hh_phic_membership_category = "Sponsored-NG(DOH)"
                )
        ) AS ng_sponsored
FROM household_tbl
WHERE barangay = "'.$barangay.'"
HAVING total_phic <> 0
```

I want to have also "HAVING ng_sponsored <> 0"

Thanks!

Comment: How about adding `where clause` instead of `HAVING`?

Comment: for that you can use where clause instead of having. having is used for aggregate function – Abadis just now edit

Comment: try this Having total_phic <> 0 and ng_sponsored<> 0

Comment: hello kabayan `:)` can you specify the table structure and tell us what are you trying to do? Congrats on your graduation anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate each `count` which satisfies the condition in a subquery. The filtering operator that is needed here is only `WHERE` and not `HAVING` because you have no further aggregation on the outer query.

```
SELECT  a.household_connector_id AS h_id,
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) + COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) AS total_phic,
        COALESCE(b.totalCountSponsored, 0) + COALESCE(c.totalCountSponsored, 0) AS ng_sponsored
FROM    household_tbl a 
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  household_connector_id, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(hh_phic_membership_category IN ('ng sponsored', 'Sponsored-NG(DOH)')) totalCountSponsored
            FROM    household_tbl
            WHERE   hh_phic_status = 1 AND 
                    age >= 21 AND 
                    age_category =  "Year"
            GROUP   BY household_connector_id           
        ) b ON a.household_connector_id = b.household_connector_id
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  household_connector_id, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(hh_phic_membership_category IN ('ng sponsored', 'Sponsored-NG(DOH)')) totalCountSponsored
            FROM    tbl_household_members 
            WHERE   hh_phic_status = 1 AND 
                    hh_age >= 21 AND 
                    hh_age_category = "Year"
            GROUP   BY household_connector_id
        ) c ON a.household_connector_id = c.household_connector_id
WHERE   a.barangay = "barangay_value_HERE" AND
        COALESCE(b.totalCount, 0) + COALESCE(c.totalCount, 0) <> 0 AND
        COALESCE(b.totalCountSponsored, 0) + COALESCE(c.totalCountSponsored, 0) <> 0
```

You cannot also use an `ALIAS` on the `WHERE` clause which is created on the same level because the `ALIAS` were created on `SELECT` clause and `WHERE` clause is executed before `SELECT`. Here's the complete SQL Order of Operation,

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

Comment: glad to hear that. did you restructure the query?

Answer (score -1):

Do this:

```
            Select * From
            (
                SELECT household_tbl.household_connector_id as h_id,
                        (SELECT COUNT(household_connector_id)
                        FROM household_tbl
                        WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
                        AND hh_phic_status = 1
                        AND age >= 21
                        AND age_category =  "Year") +

                    (SELECT COUNT(hh_members_connector_id) 
                    FROM tbl_household_members 
                    WHERE 
                    household_connector_id = h_id 
                    AND hh_phic_status = 1
                    AND hh_age >= 21 
                    AND hh_age_category = "Year") 
                    as total_phic,


                    (SELECT COUNT(household_connector_id)
                    FROM household_tbl
                    WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
                    AND hh_phic_status = 1
                    AND age >= 21
                    AND age_category =  "Year"
                    AND (hh_phic_membership_category = "ng sponsored" OR hh_phic_membership_category =  "Sponsored-NG(DOH)"))  +

                    (SELECT COUNT(hh_members_connector_id) 
                    FROM tbl_household_members
                    WHERE household_connector_id = h_id
                    AND hh_phic_status = 1
                    AND hh_age >= 21 
                    AND hh_age_category = "Year"
                    AND (hh_phic_membership_category = "ng sponsored" OR hh_phic_membership_category =  "Sponsored-NG(DOH)")) 
                    as ng_sponsored
                    FROM household_tbl WHERE barangay = "'.$barangay.'"
                )tbl Group By h_id,total_phic,ng_sponsored 
                HAVING total_phic <> 0
```

You can replace:

```
Group By h_id,total_phic,ng_sponsored HAVING total_phic <> 0
```

By

```
Where total_phic <> 0
```